# Reading Partial DateTime Input Value

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

I need to allow users to partially fill out a datetime, but the value property is not populated until it is completely validated. For example, "2017-MM-20THH:30" should be valid and readable. Is this possible with the native datetime input?

```js
input.addEventListener("click", function() {
 output.value = input.value
})
```

```html
<input id="input" type="datetime-local"><br>
Result: <output id="output">
```

Comment: You can, however, a "partial" date can not be recognized as a date, but you can save it as a "String".

Comment: Create separate control for year,  month,  day,  etc..

Comment: Just like @ElectricRouge said. Instead just one input, separate the field to as many imputs as you need. One for Year, other for month, day ,hour, seconds ...

Comment: Or just use a normal text input, but I was wondering if the datetime had that functionality.